# Doing a clean install of Windows 8.1 x64 on a SSD - should I use RAID or AHCI?

Tags: ssd, raid, format, ahci, fresh-install

when i first setup my computer about a year ago, i left it at the default AHCI when i installed windows 8. after doing so i was told by a computer tech that i should've just used RAID. i was confused as i am used to thinking of RAID in terms of RAID 0 (striping) or the other method i've used in the past is RAID 5, but never even thought of it for one solid state drive.

he explained that AHCI was a subset of RAID anyhow, but *not* the other way around, and it had to be done at the very beginning, before installing the OS or anything, so i should keep it in mind for when i do a reformat/refresh.

so here i am, ready to redo my rig, and **i'm still not sure why i should be using RAID**.

- do i not lose the ability to TRIM with RAID?
- at what point would i 'tell' the computer i want it formatted as
  RAID? In the BIOS?

i made the mistake of doing a clean install without designating any format, as i don't recall there being a choice. then after it installed, i went into the BIOS and changed it from AHCI to RAID - and it did not like that of course! :) so i switched back to AHCI, and no issues.

so i just want to make sure i do this right, *from the beginning*.

**what should i use for putting windows 8.1 x64 on my SSD: *RAID* or *AHCI*?**

thank you very much for any assistance.

Comment: The reason to use RAID (when you don't have an array) in the first place is in case you want to add other drive later to form a RAID array.  If you setup as RAID in the first place, you won't need to reformat to enable RAID later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only use RAID if you intend to use RAID functionality - striping, mirroring etc.

In all other cases just leave it as AHCI.